# "MP4" files unreadable in TV/Video players but readable in my PC and phone

Tags: video, video-conversion, tv, mp4, file-format

I download series(`.mp4` files) with my phone and copy them into the USB flash memory using OTG adapter and see them in the TV or the video player. But this week I downloaded 3 files as always but got unsupported files errors in the TV and the video players! I tested the files into my phone and also my PC and there is no problem and it shows they are healthy files with `.mp4` format and `h264` codec like always. I also used a converter and converted one of them again to `.mp4` and tested on TV and it worked! But I like to know how is it possible and why this problem happened?

I did this way a lot of time and it's the first time I have this problem.

EDIT: This is results of `ffprobe` on one of the unsupported files:

```
ffprobe version N-93719-g19af948e53 Copyright (c) 2007-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.3.1 (GCC) 20190414
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavcodec     58. 52.100 / 58. 52.100
  libavformat    58. 27.103 / 58. 27.103
  libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavfilter     7. 50.100 /  7. 50.100
  libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'blue10.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.27.102
  Duration: 00:50:29.25, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1305 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x544 [SAR 1:1 DAR 40:17], 1171 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

And this is the result of one of the supported files:

```
ffprobe version N-93719-g19af948e53 Copyright (c) 2007-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.3.1 (GCC) 20190414
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavcodec     58. 52.100 / 58. 52.100
  libavformat    58. 27.103 / 58. 27.103
  libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavfilter     7. 50.100 /  7. 50.100
  libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'blue9.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:51:46.25, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 926 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x544 [SAR 1:1 DAR 40:17], 791 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Comment: The original creator (where you downloaded from) may have changed their codec choice/configuration... without asking them you won't know... you could find an application to compare the metadata, I guess... The fact you've re-compressed/converted the files and they work would back this theory up...

Comment: Could you run `ffprobe yourfile.mp4` on a machine with ffmpeg installed and provide the results?

Comment: @grawity: Can I do this command on Windows 10 CMD?

Comment: There are ffmpeg builds for Windows, I think the current official source is https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/. WSL would also work. If you can, show the output for both working and non-working MP4 files.

Comment: There are many different "levels" of h.264. It sounds like your TV/video player simply does not support the higher levels while your phone does.

Comment: @grawity: I did and edited my question.

Comment: The "encoder" has changed ...

Comment: @DavidPostill How can I fix it? Should I use a video converter app or there is an esear way?